# How to convert two columns from a data frame to Map(col1, col2) in scala?

Tags: scala, dictionary, dataframe

How to convert rwo columns from a data frame to Map(col1, col2) in scala ?

I tried :

```
 val resultMap = df.select($"col1", $"col2")
    .map ({
      case Row(a:String, b: String) => Map(a.asInstanceOf[String] ->b.asInstanceOf[String] )
    })
```

But I couldn't able to get the values from this map. Is there any other way to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

There is no Dataset Encoder for Map[String, String], I'm not even sure you can actually make one at all.

Here are two versions, one which is unsafe and other which is safe, to do what you want to do. Effectively you'll need to reduce to RDD level to do the computation:

```
case class OnFrame(df: DataFrame) {

  import df.sparkSession.implicits._

  /**
    * If input columns don't match we'll fail at query evaluation.
    */
  def unsafeRDDMap: RDD[Map[String, String]] = {
    df.rdd.map(row => Map(row.getAs[String]("col1") -> row.getAs[String]("col2")))
  }

  /**
    * Use Dataset-to-case-class mapping.
    * If input columns don't match we'll fail before query evaluation.
    */
  def safeRDDMap: RDD[Map[String, String]] = {
    df
      .select($"col1" as "key", $"col2" as "value")
      .as[OnFrame.Entry]
      .rdd
      .map(_.toMap)
  }

  def unsafeMap(): Map[String, String] = {
    unsafeRDDMap.reduce(_ ++ _)
  }

  def safeMap(): Map[String, String] = {
    safeRDDMap.reduce(_ ++ _)
  }

}
```

If you provide more clearly what your goal is perhaps we could this even more efficiently as collecting everything into a single map is a potential Spark anti-pattern - meaning your data fits into the driver.

Comment: I am using spark 1.6, data set concept is  >2.0 can I still use this ?

Comment: Only the unsafe version. Your import will have to change to `df.sqlContext.implicits._`.